# Creating a nested dictionary comprehension for year and month in python

Tags: dictionary-comprehension

I would like to create a nested dictionary with dict comprehension but I am getting syntax error.

```
years = [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]
months = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

my_Dict = {i:{j: for j in months}, for i in years}
```

I am not sure how to declare this nested dict comprehension without getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the correct way would be to use a dictionary with a nested list comprehension because if you use a nested dictionary, it will replace old values. The correct syntax, in this case, would be this one:

```py
years = [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]
months = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

my_Dict = {
    year: [month for month in months] for year in years
}
print(my_Dict)

>>> {2016: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 
     2017: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 
     2018: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 
     2019: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made some slight changes to the code above and this works

```
key_years = {2016, 2017, 2018, 2019}
key_months = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}

myDict = {i:{j for j in key_months} for i in key_years}
print (myDict)
```

Output: {2016: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, 2017: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, 2018: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, 2019: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}}